# unable to store output in a variable also not able to export result to any file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have written following commands:

```
$env:Path += "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin"
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java" -version
```

I am trying to store output of second line in a variable but unable to do so. Also tried to export output in some file, that also did not work. Please assist.

Comment: `java.exe` might be writing the version output to `stderr`. Try `$version = (& "C:\program files(x86)\java\jre6\bin\java" -version 2>&1).Exception.Message`

Comment: Thanks Mathias R. Jessen , your solution worked for me.

Comment: I've added a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

`java.exe` might be writing the version output to `stderr`.

You can merge the error stream (`2`) into the standard output stream (`1`) with a stream redirection operator (`>&`) like so:

```
& "C:\program files(x86)\java\jre6\bin\java" -version 2>&1
```

PowerShell will try to be helpful and wrap the error output in an `ErrorRecord`. Since we just need the plaintext output, grab the `Message` value from the `Exception` wrapped by it:

```
$jversion = (& "C:\program files(x86)\java\jre6\bin\java" -version 2>&1).Exception.Message
```

`$jversion` will now contain one or more strings as output by `java.exe`

See the [`about_Redirection` help file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) for more information